# Lebesgue measure on probability measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I need your help for this question

> Let $\, \mathbb{P}_x, \mathbb{P}_y \,and\, \mathbb{P}_z \,are\,
>  the\, laws \, of \, 3 \, r.v. $ If  $\,\, \mathbb{P}_x=\mathbb{P}_y\, $then $\,\,
>  \mathbb{P}_x\otimes \mathbb{P}_z=\mathbb{P}_y\otimes \mathbb{P}_z$?

I know that if $X$ and $Y$are independent $\mathbb{P}_x\otimes \mathbb{P}_y$ it's going to give me the distrbution of the random vector $(x,y)$ then the problem it's the prove that the distribution of $(Y,Z)$ and $(X,Z)$ aren't equal
But what if $X$ and $Y$ aren't independent of $Z$

What would be the general solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any measurable rectangle $A\times B$ we have $(P_x\otimes P_z)( A\times B)=P_x(A)P_z(B)=P_y(A)P_z(B)=(P_y\otimes P_z)( A\times B)$. Hence $(P_x\otimes P_z)(E)=(P_x\otimes P_z)(E)$ whenever $E$ is a finite disjoint union of measurable rectangles. These sets form an algebra which generates the product sigma algebra and hence $(P_x\otimes P_z)(E)=(P_y\otimes P_z)(E)$ for all $E$ in the the product sigma algebra.

Comment: $(P_x\otimes P_z)( A\times B)=P_x(A)P_z(B)=P_y(A)P_z(B)$ on this line you're implying independence?

Comment: @AbrahamBerrielRangel That is the definition of product measure.

Comment: @AbrahamBerrielRangel If your intention was really to ask of $F_X=F_Y$ implies $F_{(X,Z)}=F_{(Y,Z)}$ the the answer is NO. Take $Y=-X$ where $X$ has $N(0,1)$ distribution and $Z=X$ for  a counter-example.

Comment: No, i really want a Measure point of view and not a probabilistic one, it is true?

Comment: @AbrahamBerrielRangel Product of the probability measures induced by two random variables always corresponds to the joint measure under independence. The very definition of product measure reflects the definition of independence. Since your question is about product measures, independenece is automatic here.

Comment: But then there's a reason why on the measure side are equal but on the probability one not?

Comment: The moment you write $P_X\otimes P_Z$ are assuming independence of $X$  and $Z$. In general you should write $P_{X,Z}$. So in this question  you do have $P(X \in A,Z \in B)=P(X \in A) P(Z \in B)$ etc.

Comment: Thanks for all the attention :)